# What is the most number of repetitions in a GM game?

Tags: rules, draw, grandmaster, records, fivefold-repetition

In [July 2014 FIDE introduced new rules](https://handbook.fide.com/chapter/E012014) regarding draws. The arbiter was required to step in and declare the game drawn in cases where the players repeated the position 5 times:

> 9.6  If one or both of the following occur(s) then the game is drawn:
>
> a. the same position has appeared, as in 9.2b, for at least five consecutive alternate moves by each player.
> b. any consecutive series of 75 moves have been completed by each player without the movement of any pawn and without any capture. If the last move resulted in checkmate, that shall take precedence.

Of course long before this players have been able to claim a draw for a 3-fold repetition. Nevertheless, the new 5-fold repetition rule allowed players to force the arbiter's hand in tournaments where early draws were forbidden.

Since the rule change in 2014 what is the most number of repetitions in a FIDE rated game where both players are GMs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most number I have found so far is in [this game from 2015](https://old.chesstempo.com/gamedb/game/3831630)

```
[fen ""]
[Title "Narciso Dublan vs Grigoryan 38th Barbera Open 2015 "]

1.e4 c5 2.Nc3 e6 3.g3 d5 4.exd5 exd5 5.Bg2 d4 6.Qe2+ Be7 7.Nd5 Nc6 8.d3 Be6 9.Nf4 Bc8 10.Nd5 Be6 11.Nf4 Bc8 12.Nd5 Be6 13.Nf4 Bc8 14.Nd5 Be6 15.Nf4 Bc8 16.Nd5 Be6 17.Nf4 Bc8 18.Nd5 Be6 19.Nf4 Bc8 20.Nd5 Be6 21.Nf4 Bc8 22.Nd5 Be6 23.Nf4 Bc8 24.Nd5 Be6 25.Nf4 Bc8 26.Nd5 Be6 27.Nf4 Bc8 28.Nd5 Be6 29.Nf4 Bc8 30.Nd5 Be6 31.Nf4 Bc8 1/2-1/2
```

That is a remarkable **12 repetitions** before the game was declared drawn! Perhaps there was a 30 move requirement before the game was allowed to be declared drawn and the arbiter paid more attention to this than article 9.6.